# Django migration error (SQL to PostgreSQL): return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I created a dump.json file from my SQL local DB. After that, I uploaded my file to the server prepared for PostgreSQL and I caught the following error after using the following commands:

```
python3 manage.py shell  
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> ContentType.objects.all().delete()
>>> quit()

python manage.py loaddata dump.json
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "posts_group" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "posts_group" SET "title" = 'Котики', "slug" = 'cats'...
               ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/yatube/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/yatube/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 181, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 223, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 780, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 853, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 903, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 760, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1471, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1142, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/farexzon/hw05_final/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Problem installing fixture '/home/farexzon/hw05_final/yatube/dump.json': Could not load posts.Group(pk=1): relation "posts_group" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "posts_group" SET "title" = 'Котики', "slug" = 'cats'...
```

I've checked the versions of Django versions on the local machine and the server, checked the creation of all migrations, Settings.by settings - and still the error.
ChatGPT suggested that I check the migrations and versions of the packages, we did not think of anything else.
Django 2.2.6, but only one different - local base python 3.7, server 3.10, and i can't change it now.

My settings.py DATABASES:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_ENGINE', 'django.db.backends.postgresql'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT')
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you do this `ContentType.objects.all().delete()`? Pretty sure that just wiped out all the model information Django needs per [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).